# UIEvent.predictedTouches(for:UITouch) array empty most of the time

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, uikit

Running the following code in iOS 10.0.2 on a iPhone 6s

```
override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    print("-moved-")
    print(event!.predictedTouches(for: touches.first!)!.count)
}
```

Predicted touches exist maybe 1 out of 5 times. Same on an iPad mini retina running 9.3

I was hoping to use native touch prediction to get around the fact that the rate of touchesMoved firing jumps erratically between 60fps and ~30fps.

Comment: wouldn't multiplying by delta time work better?

Comment: Are you suggesting just handing the prediction myself?